# How can I get width and height of big image after displaying it on html-page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a big image, in example 10000x8000px. In this case I reduce width and height of image using CSS class **.myClass { max-width: 90vw; max-height: 80vh; }** How can I get width and height of this image after displaying it on html-page. In example, if I have 1200x800 monitor I want to get result 960x640px using **$(img).width()** or **$(img).height()**. Is it possible? When I use **$(img).width()** or **$(img).height()** a get natural size 10000x8000px. And **img.clientWidth** return 0.

Comment: can you create a demo for this? [As you can see here](http://jsfiddle.net/1e2murax/) jQuery is not showing the behaviour you described in this demo.

Comment: I create a demo with my code http://jsfiddle.net/ruvp2odL/ . It works. Maybe problem in line **img.src = "data:image/png;base64," + encode64image;**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I understand is that you want to reduce size of image if it is too big. Assume `div.image` is an image in the code below and check the code. Use this code to get desired result what you want..

```js
var width = $(".image").width();
var height = $(".image").height();

if(width > 900) {
  
 var newWidth = (width * 80) / 100; // reduce to 80% width
  $(".image").css("width", newWidth);
  
  
}

if(height > 900) {
 var newHeight = (height * 80) / 100; // reduce to 80% width
   $(".image").css("height", newHeight);
}
```

```css
.image{
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: blue;
  display:block;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="image">
</div>
```